# Trying to Add one more Child in GetContent() in Task node

Tags: roku, brightscript

I follow a CustomGrid_ContentManager From an SGGraph Example. Here Below the Function for getting content from the feed.

```
sub GetContent()
    feed = ReadAsciiFile("pkg:/images/Response.json")
    if feed.Len() > 0
        json = ParseJson(feed)
        if json <> invalid and json.rows <> invalid and json.rows.Count() > 0
            rootChildren = {
                children: []
            }
           for each row in json.rows
               if row.items <> invalid
                   rowAA = {
                       children: []
                   }
                 for each item in row.items
                     rowAA.children.Push(item)
                end for
                rowAA.Append({ title: row.title })
               rootChildren.children.Push(rowAA)
            end if
       end for
       m.top.content.Update(rootChildren)
      end if
   end if
end sub
```

And I access the response using the MainScene like below :

```
m.grid.content.GetChild(0).GetChild(0)
```

Here, I'm trying to Add a one more child in GetContent() and access using in main scene like below.

```
m.grid.content.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).GetChild(0)
```

But no luck. It's everytime found invalid Data. I'm trying using the below code for . Does anyone give a suggestion how to do this?

```
sub GetContent()
    feed = ReadAsciiFile("pkg:/images/Response.json")
    if feed.Len() > 0
        json = ParseJson(feed)
        if json <> invalid and json.rows <> invalid and json.rows.Count() > 0
            rootChildren = {
                children: []
            }
            ' 'First Way Here I added extra Node 
            ' rowNode = {
            ' children: []
            ' }

            ' 'Second Way Here I added extra Node 
            ' rootChildren = {
            '    children: {
            '      rowNode : []
            '    }
            ' }

           for each row in json.rows
               if row.items <> invalid
                   rowAA = {
                       children: []
                   }
                 for each item in row.items
                    'First way using a for loop
                    ' for each nik in item.items
                    '     rowNode.children.Push(nik)
                    ' end for
                    ' rowAA.children.Push(rowNode) ' But Here not maintain item value for first node

                    ' 'Second way I tried with directly addd
                    ' rootChildren.children.rowNode.Push(item.items) 'But here It's give and error
                     rowAA.children.Push(item)
                end for
                rowAA.Append({ title: row.title }) 'Here Second Way It's give a error not update data here
               rootChildren.children.Push(rowAA)
            end if
       end for
       m.top.content.Update(rootChildren)
      end if
   end if
end sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to get content before view was shown using ComponentController? Please provide info where are you trying to get content in your MainScene.

Comment: @hornyhedgehog yes

Answer (score 0):

Actually SGDEX Content Manager connects to view **only after** it was shown using ComponentController. Only after that your Content Manager task will start execution of GetContent() function of your ContentHandler.
Try to get content after view was shown.

Comment: Yes that thing I know. But, I'm trying to add one more child in My GetContent() it's extends with ContentHandler. So, I'm able to access that child in MainScene. It's same thing like a rowlist Component(In Rowlist one child for a title and second for a content). I required third Child.

Comment: Looks like you are using root content loading model, and you are trying to get content before it set.
Is grid visible at moment when your try to get child of content?
Or spinner is visible at this moment?
It matters because ContentHandler is executed in other thread, so you could get race condition.

Comment: At first I unable to make a child. I'm trying two ways as mention in question. Grid is not visible when I'm fetching the content(It means making the child). It's visible when I'm accessing the content.

Comment: Could you please provide sample of your JSON feed so i would be able to try it locally?

Comment: First think i found is that you are observing rowItemFocused, not rowItemSelected. Is it expected? If you will add same alias for rowItemSelected it will work as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221637/discussion-between-hornyhedgehog-and-nikunj-chaklasiya).

Comment: Is there any other way to add a child? Because 
rowAA.children.Update({children:[
{title:item.items}
]}) is not work for me

Comment: because Update method works only with roSGNode, not assocArray

Comment: Ok But Push is also not work and append works But It's adding with same content. Not Consider as Child